# EXCEL selecting columns according to value of first raw with increasing increment of 1

Tags: excel, macros, selection, intervals

I have a 2 column very long numeric data. Data image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClJf8.jpg). I am in need of sampling/selecting rows with respect to column A for each integer interval of "1". for example 1 row from <1, another row from integer value 1, another from integer value: 2. etc. going through 1700 and so forth. A sample of what is literally meant is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSdqD.jpg).
What type of macro should I use in order to obtain this selection method?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `index(match())` to do this. Just create a list of integers starting at 1 and ending at whatever your max is. Then, assuming your list is in `A1:B27` and your list of INTs starts at `D1`, then in `E1`:

```
=INDEX(B1:B27,MATCH(D1,A1:A27,1),1)
```

And copy it down. The second parameter on Match will detect the last value before your integer value in `D1`. This is off by 1, so ultimately you'll have to subtract one from each integer to rectify the list, but it should give you a sample.

[image]

Comment: That has been a solution for my problem. The decimals of the A column values and the corresponding values in the B column in actual data are very close to each other, and the small offset is totally negligible for the case. Thank you very much for the prompt response.